# Filtering and changing list React

Tags: reactjs, list

I have two lists passed to child component by parent. Looks like this:

```
render() {
  const {selectedItems, items} = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Checkbox
          key={item.id}
          name={item.name}
          checked={this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item.id) > -1}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}>
          {item.name}
        </Checkbox>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I was trying to handle onChange event and keep selected items in the list selectedItems, but not sure how to do it. Does anyone has idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking selectedItems from the props, it means that the value has been given to your component from a parent one, which might have a state where it keeps it.

This means that you have to have a sort of onChange handler passed down via props that you call this way:

```
...
const {selectedItems, items, onChange} = this.props;
...
return (
  ...
  onChange={ onChange }>
  ...
```

Then, in your parent component you will render your component way:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Checklist
      selectedItems={ this.state.selectedItems }
      items={ this.state.items }
      onChange={ this.handleChange }
    />
  )
}
```

Also, in the parent component you'll have the `handleChange` itself, which will update the state with selected items:

```
handleChange e => {
  const newSelectedItems = // your logic to update the selectedItems list
  // this.setState({ selectedItems: newSelectedItems })
}
```

Do you need a more detailed explanation or this brief is ok?

Comment: Actually both list are taken from backend -> both as props as I assume (Im new to react...).

Comment: Im assigning this.props.selectedItems to state and want to keep it this way

Comment: You take them from the backend with an API call, but surely you put them into the state somewhere, or in redux. I don't understand your last comment. You already did it or what?

Comment: redux, true. but then Im mapping state to props.

Comment: If you are using redux, then, in the handleChange you have to dispatch an action to start the redux mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up `state` and `props` by the looks of it. I'll assume you want to keep the `selectedItems` list in the state?

If so, you will need to add/remove the itemId from the selectedItems list. There are multiple ways you can do this. One of these methods is by using the [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function.

```
class Checkboxes extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: [],
  };

  handleChange = itemId => {
    const selectedItems = this.state.selectedItems.slice();

    if (selectedItems.indexOf(itemId) > -1) {
      selectedItems.splice(selectedItems.indexOf(itemId), 1);
    } else {
      selectedItems.push(itemId);
    }

    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Checkbox
            key={item.id}
            name={item.name}
            checked={selectedItems.indexOf(item.id) > -1}
            onChange={() => this.handleChange(item.id)}>
            {item.name}
          </Checkbox>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: both are taken from backend as props-> list of available items and list of items selected. Im assinging selectedItems to state

Comment: So the initial `selectedItems` should be coming from your backend?

Comment: Thank you so much, this works the way I wanted! Do you recommend any book/tutorial/anything to learn React maybe? ;)

Comment: yes, both comes from backend. Then I want to send the changes back to backend